# Trying on potential Shatnez clothing

Tags: halacha, inspection, shaatnez, kavana-intent

How can one try on clothing before checking, if it might contain Shatnez?

Comment: duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6110/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mishna in Kelayim Perek 9 says that those that sell Shatnez are allowed to try it on in order to model it to the Purchaser. According to this Shita you would be allowed **to try it on** prior to purchasing. However we do not Pasken like that. The Heter to try it on is based on Rov, since most clothing is not Shatnez, and as it is not yours you can not check it. However once you purchase it and you can verify whether it is or isn't Shatnez then you are not allowed to wear it till it is checked as it is (Efsher Livarer) possible to check.

Heard from one of the checkers at the Flatbush Shaatnez Lab

Comment: The really expensive suits acctualy have a Chazakah that they do Have Shatnez I wonder what the din is there as do the Russian Hats (bought in Russia) So i still wonder

Comment: I will try to find out next time I speak to them.

Comment: What is your source for "we do not Pasken like that"? Rema to Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 301:6 cites Tur, Rosh and Smag that one may wear shaatnez to model the fit.

Comment: A discussion of a seller of clothes who wishes to show it's length by placing it upon himself does not have anything to do with a buyer whatsoever. The difference of course is psik reisha. See all the commentaries there in Shulchan Aruch y'd 301 Siff 5&6. And concerning this idea that you don't need to check because it's someone else's: what? Where is that chidush found? Sounds made up.