# Trying on Shatnez

Tags: shaatnez, kavana-intent

If I know a suit is Shatnez Like all Hugo Boss suits or the  [Russian Hats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushanka) bought in Russia (usually Uman or Lizensk) can I try them on as I know i will remove the Shatnez later and does being Sephardi or ashkenazi make a difference?

Comment: And what about if I don't know it's Shatnez (or should that be another question)?

Comment: see here.......


http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/5592/shatnez-issur-clothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the item is known to be shatnez, to try it on for size would be prohibited according to the Beis Yosef, and permitted according to the Rama. Thus, ashkenazim and sephardim should follow their respective authorities. See here: http://home.comcast.net/~shatnez/halacha1.html

Comment: Links is bad...